# Angular 5: set formControl validation state as valid manually

Tags: angular

I don't know if it is my code or default behaviour. Anyway, I have a control with validity set to a date that is today or in the past. It does work well. My problem is for specific cases, the element can be populated from ngOnInit with an acceptable format. Yet, the form still insists it is invalid. I have to go to the control and manually enter the date that was generated by the system.

What do I have to do?

I did try to set it as valid using:

```
  this.form.controls['date'].setErrors(null)
```

However, its value becomes null (instead of just the errors) and I still have to write the date myself to pass it.

Comment: You're trying to circumvent the problem rather than fixing it. If the field should be valid, but is not, you have a bug somewhere. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Try this:  
  `this.form.get('date').setErrors(null)`

Comment: @NadhirFalta You should have written an answer, so now I could upvote it. Thanks ;).

Comment: @tastydb I added an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

You can do this: `this.form.get('date').setErrors(null)`

`.get('date')` will get you the full `FormControl`

Answer (score 2):

this.form.get('date').setErrors(null) works pretty well or ur can simply return an object  { dateError: true }.

But beaware that if u need two or more formControl values in your custom validator, you have to put the validator initialization in formGroup , not in formControl.

```
private setFormgroup(){
   this.myFormGroup = this.formbuilder.group({
          name: [name, { validators: Validators.required }],
          price: [price, { validators: [singleValueCustomValidator] }],

          { validators: this.multiValueCustomValidator });
  }
```

See this article for full example. https://medium.com/@monir.khan.developer/angular-10-custom-form-validation-example-reactive-forms-3f5432a21fff

Comment: Returning an object `{dateError: true}` will set the field to invalid not valid.